# cross sections/volume calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

Can volume be negative? To try to be specific, i'm trying the find the volume of a triangle that has a cross section perpendicular to the x axis. After doing all the math and setting up the integral, my final answer for the volume is negative( Don't think this would help at all but just in case the integral is from 0 to 4 (4-x^2)dx). The graph shows that the triangle is negative as well(below x axis quadrant 4). So going back to my initial questions, can volume be negative? or should I just switch the sign to make the answer positive?

Edited: $\int_0^4{\left(4-x^2\right)dx}$

Comment: How sure are you that you really want to integrate up to $4$ instead of up to $2$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was 4 because the two initial equations given were x=y^2+4y and x=4, therefore I put the bounds as 0 to 4

Comment: hold on i think you were right